# sphinx rt & python: how send long sql query?

Tags: python, search, sphinx, pymysql

I am use use sphinx rt
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/rt-overview.html
Sphinx 2.2.11-id64-release (95ae9a6)
and PyMySQL - Python MySQL Client
https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL
PyMySQL==0.8.0

It's perfect work, for short text.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO `rt_file_notes` (`id`, `line_number`, `text`)  " \
          "VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
p = 'hello'
result = cursor.execute(sql, (1, 1, p))
```

But when I try send to index large text,
the PyMySQL try to split sql query and to send more then one requests

and i have error

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'row 1, column 2: string expected\x00')
```

- sphinx:
  select @@max_allowed_packet;
  8388608
- PyMySQL: 
  pymysql.connections.MAX_PACKET_LEN=2**24-1  # 16777215

what can to do at this situation?
i would like use rt mode.
as one choose -to set another limits for query
or split text to N chunks and to index them as difference records.

my be has more bettor solution for this problem?
*also what is better python client for sphinx?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting max_packet_size on Sphinx side? http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-max-packet-size